# Hide a container when Hover a menu item CSS

Tags: css

My website: https://nycphoto.pixl.work/delete/

I have a container under the Header which I want to HIDE when the Photo Booth menu is hover. You can check it here:

[image]

ID of the Photo Booth menu item: #menu-item-7912
ID of the container under the Header: #mega-menu-customized

So far I have tried the following:

```
.menu-item.menu-item-7912:hover + #mega-menu-customized{
font-size: 90px !important;
background-color: blue !important;
display: none !important;
}
```

This doesn't work.

Is it possible to reach the Mega menu container using CSS to hide it?

Comment: You will need JS to do so. on #menu-item-7912 hover event, you can toggle the class of #mega-menu-customized div.

Comment: "The + combinator selects adjacent siblings. This means that the second element directly follows the first, and both share the same parent." - in other words: please add your html...

Comment: @A.Meshu the html is created by the theme, the site is done on Wordpress using a theme, so it's a mess to share the code.

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala I am going to try with JS, probably that's the reason is not working

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala i have done it this way, but without success:
<script>
let test = document.getElementByClassName(".menu-item.menu-item-7912");

test.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
document.getElementById('test2').style.display = 'none';
 });

test.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {

 document.getElementById('mega-menu-customized').style.display = 'block';
 
});


</script>
I tested this code on JSFiddle and works but not on my website: https://nycphoto.pixl.work/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example.

I am toggling `hide` class on div2 on hover of div1.

```js
let div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
let div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

div1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  div2.classList.add("hide");
});

div1.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  div2.classList.remove("hide");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 10px;
}

#div1 {
  background: #66000040;
}

#div2 {
  background: #00660040;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div id='div1'>div 1</div>
<div id='div2'>div 2</div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks! i checked it on Jsfiddle and it works nice. Unfortunately it doesn't work on my website. Im notsure if there's something blocking the javascript. 
I have also tried the following:   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script>
$("#menu-item-7912").on("mouseover",function(){
    $("#mega-menu-customized").css({
        display:"block"
    })
});

$("#menu-item-7912").on("mouseout",function(){
    $("#mega-menu-customized").css({
        display:"none"
    })
});
</script>

Comment: @Alejo_Blue try including jquery from other CDN services such as cdnjs.com

Comment: In that case, you also need to share your code

Comment: hey! this one gave me an idea of how to implement, i used most of your code, but i have to initialize the javascript like this jQuery(document).ready(function(){ thanks bro